# Question regarding indirect object pronoun "Le"

Tags: gramática

Good afternoon,

I got a bit confused regarding indirect object pronoun "Le".

For example, "Me gustaría decirle" would translate as "I would like to tell him/her/You". Here everything seems clear, as I would clearly associate "le" with "him/to him". So I always can easily use in everyday's speech something like this: "Ask him" - "Pregúntale" or "Give to him" - "Dale", but examples below seem not to follow the rule above:

1) "Me gustaría le continuaras" - "I would like you to continue". Here "le" is not used in the meaning "him/to You". So why simply not to tell like this: "Me gustaría que continuaras".

2) "Los hombres de Doyle le tienen miedo" - Doyle's guys are scared of him. Here "le" is not used in the meaning "him". So why simply not to say like this: "Los hombres de Doyle tiene miedo de él".

3) Same here, but in plural: "¿No les temes?" - "And are you not scared of them?"

4) "Ahora le relevo de sus obligaciones." - "I relieve you of your obligations now". Here "le" is used to say "take from you", but not "give to him/You". So Here why not to say like this: "Ahora relevo usted de sus obligaciones".

Additional separate example that I never encountered before:

5) "Me gustaría le pedimos que nos ayuden" - "I would ask you to help us." Here why not to say like this: "Me gustaría pedirle que nos ayuden". I don't understand why "pedir" is in nosotros form (in the original sentence). Even though use of "le" here I can understand. Maybe the correct translation to English would be: "I would like that we ask you to help us".

Perhaps there are rules for this, but I haven't seen them anywhere.

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: There are several confusions among the questions. Number 1 seems to be a mistake or a truncated sentence. Numbers 2 and 3 are the same and refer to different but equivalent argument types to *temer* and *tener miedo*. Numbers 2, 3, and 4 show confusion between clitic and full object pronouns. Number 5 is a mistake.

Comment: Dear pablodf76, I looked at the explanation in the link given by walen, but still would like to double check. Ok, so numbers 1 and 5 we exclude. Could you please explain why le and les are used in numbers 2, 3 and 4? Which types of dative case is used in each case and why?

Comment: As I said, numbers 1 and 5 are simply mistakes (ungrammatical sentences). 2 and 3 are the same, so if you're not satisfied with the answer and still have doubts, you could try asking a question about that, explaining why you don't understand it. In #4 I don't really understand what you mean by that reference to "give".

Comment: Number 4 is actually a mistake, I found it out. "lo" should be used instead of "le", because there is a direct object who is about to be releaved from command. So it would be: "I relieve you  (Usted = lo) of your command"

Comment: Regarding your last comment about number 4 -- this *le/lo* choice is somewhat regional.  To me, "Ahora le relevo de sus obligaciones" looks fine.  // General tip: if you want to ask about a sentence you read somewhere, please provide a reference or a link; if you want to ask about a sentence you composed yourself, be explicit about that.  It will be easier for people to help you if you follow this format.

Comment: Thank you. Acknowledged/

Comment: Voting to reopen as there are some parts of this question that are not covered in the proposed duplicate.  It would be nice to give OP an answer in an answer box, not just in comments.

Comment: Could you clarify that for these questions?  Either in a comment or by editing the question?  For example, I think I have something helpful to say regarding #1.

Comment: I don't know what the best approach would be for this. Is it good practice to (radically) edit a question (meaning: taking out large chunks of it) after it has been discussed and/or closed?

Comment: @pablodf76 - When a question gets closed, OP is advised to edit the question to resolve whatever problem resulted in its closure.  Also, the community is encouraged to do civic-minded editing to "rescue" a question.  (In this case, I think OP would be the one to clarify.)  As an example, if the question isn't clear, the way it is originally written, and then it gets closed, hopefully OP provides the needed clarification.